# ASP.NET Framework 4.0 [ArgumentException: Unknown web method getDescription. Parameter name: methodName]

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I was using the jQuery to retrieve data from SQL server. The code works fine on my personal computer (ASP.NET Framework 4.5 + SQL server 2008 R2) but when I tried to deploy it on the commercial server (ASP.NET Framework 4.0.30319 + SQL server 2008 R2), it kept popping up the "unknown web method" 500 Internal Server Error. Please Help.

The method is like this:

```
public class rt300default : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
  [WebMethod, ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false)]
   public static string getDescription ()
   {
      return "XXX";
   }
 }
```

The call is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "rt300default.aspx/getDescription",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
    }
    })
});
```

Please help with the error message that as below:

Stack Trace:

```
[ArgumentException: Unknown web method getDescription.Parameter name: methodName]
 System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule.OnPostAcquireRequestState(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) +727543
 System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +92
 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165
```

Exception Details:

```
System.ArgumentException: Unknown web method getDescription. Parameter name: methodName
```

Any Thoughts? Thanks

Comment: if you type rt300default.aspx/getDescription in browser, what happend?

Comment: try call webservice from another app, like fiddler and check if it does work

Comment: Fiddler will also give you information on any error headers thrown by the web method.

Comment: If I type rt300default.aspx/getDescription, the page will show on the browser with three syntax error: File: jquery-1.11.3.min.js, Line: 3, Column: 1; File: jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js, Line: 3, Column: 1; File: ciidata.js, Line: 3, Column: 1 . It refers to the beginning of all .js files. @DanielVorph

Comment: I could not install any software on this machine, due to admin access. But I tried using MS visual studio 2013 to create a complete new project with web services.asmx, it seems works. The "Hello World" was shown on the browser. @DanielVorph

Comment: Thanks Jon, but I cannot install any new software on this machine, including Fiddler. @JonP

Comment: I'm assuming you can't install on the server. How about your local machine? If so fiddler can be used to inspect the network calls/headers for the ajax call. I think you can even get a fiddler plug in for firefox.

Comment: On my local personal laptop, this app works just fine. No error at all. What I meant was I cannot install any software on the computer that is owned by this institute I am working with. It needs an admin access to do so. I may have to wait until tomorrow to see this possibility @JonP

Comment: the webservice and caller are on the same server?

Comment: I am not sure if I have the correct answer to this question. But I will ask who for sure knows that and get back to you. The webservice is in the code behind code and the caller is the JavaScript. Both of the two files are running on the same computer.There is only one server on this institute, so I believe they are on the same server. @DanielVorph

Comment: can you install fiddler on other machine not in the server? if you can then test de webservice, it must be a machine in the same network